# netplan 3 interfaces 2 vlans

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I need 3 IPs on my server (ubuntu 20).

my netplan configuration look like

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
  vlans:
      eno2:
          id: 200
          link: eno1
          addresses: [A/24]
      eno3:
          id: 300
          link: eno1
          addresses: [B/24]
```

to apply change I use "netplan apply" then I reboot the server.

work

```
 curl --interface eno1 http://ifconfig.io
```

Doesn't work

```
 curl --interface eno2 http://ifconfig.io
 curl --interface eno3 http://ifconfig.io
```

A and B are 2 IPs that I can ping.

Did I missed something in my netplan's conf ?

Answer (score 0):

Your additional interfaces have no routes aside from the local route; so using these interfaces will not allow you to route traffic to the Internet.  To configure these vlan interfaces to reach the Internet, you will need to add a 0.0.0.0/0 route to each interface.

You will also need to use routing policies, to ensure traffic for each interface is handled symmetrically, rather than having multiple default routes that interfere with one another.

Also, if your only goal is to have three IP addresses, there is a much simpler way to do this without the use of VLANs:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [A/24]
      addresses: [B/24]
```

You do not have to configure a different interface, or use VLANs, in order to have multiple addresses.  If there are other reasons that you require the different addresses to be on separate segments, then VLANs may be appropriate, but they are certainly more complex.

Answer (score 0):

if you have one network interface

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses:
            - 10.0.0.10/24
            - 11.0.0.11/24
            - 12.0.0.12/24
      nameservers:
           addresses:
              - 8.8.8.8
              - 8.8.4.4
```

and other parameters you use